# Scite4autohotkey installer gives me no features

Tags: editor, autohotkey, scite

When I use the installer from the author's website, I end up with a program that seems to have no support for autohotkey editing, no syntax hiliting, (not even a language to deal with .ahk files), no ahk specific tools in the toolbar, debuger support, help file, and so on.  In fact, the only thing I see is a changed 'About...' in the Help menu.

Is there some setup I'm missing, or is the current version broken?

Comment: What version of AutoHotkey do you have installed? Where did you download SciTE4AutoHotkey from?

Comment: Version v1.1.22.03 32-bit, had (64-bit version same effect)  As stated above, I got SciTE4AutoHotkey from the authors site: fincs.ahk4.net/scite4ahk/

Comment: Do have any of the installed files, say under programfiles/AutoHotkey/scite ? Or documents/AutoHotkey/scite ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but after a longer period there has been an update.
The latest version can be found [here](https://github.com/fincs/SciTE4AutoHotkey/releases/latest).